# Setting up sites with lists and custom content types

Tags: 2010, development, best-practices

I am creating a proof of concept at work. It will be creating a web applciation with a site collection in it. The site collection will have 1 or 2 custom content types and a few lists set up. I will turn some features on such as in place reocrds managment and document ids.

This is fine I can click through all the options on my dev machine to do this. What is the best way to get all these changes live?

Should I write down my steps to reproduce. Do I jutt take a backup of the site collection and restore it to a production web application or can I capture the setup in code?

Only one instance of this solution will be needed so I dont need the ability to ceate 5 of these in live.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save your site as site template. See [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-HA101782501.aspx). Then open site templates library and download the template to your machine. After this you can upload template to your prodaction environment and activate template.

Comment: My only warning is be very careful with what features are activated on this site when you save the template, including other site and list template features.